# Rollmean with element value dependant window?

Tags: r

I'm looking for a fast way to do following:

There is a factor F with M levels and length N. Where N is huge (millions). M is thousands.
I want to calculate for each element X in F rolling frequency of X's level within F.

For example if we have 2 levels and factor [1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2] then for rolling window 3 the result supposed to be [1/3, 1/3, 2/3, 1, 1/3, 2/3, 1/3, 2/3, 2/3, 2/3, 2/3, 1, 1/3]

That could be done with zoo::rollmean (pseudocode):

```
res <- rep(NA, N)
foreach level in {M}
{
ids <- which (F == M)
res[ids] <- rollmean(F == M, 3, fill = 0, align="right") [ids] # running rollmean over logical vector. First 3 elem will be wrong as i did't find suitable fill parameter.
}
```

*EDIT: if you run pseudocode above you'll get slightly wrong result (first two values will be corrupted) as I didn't find right fill= param for rollmean() to make it work for first 2 elements and window 3 as I assumed.*

But this is damn slow, bcs logical vector is sparse (most values are False).

What I would like to do is to generate seq(1, N) (list of indexes) and split it with tapply() by F's levels. This will give me a list of indexes for each level.
Than would be great to go over each list and for each index there find if there are any indexes less than it but greater than (index - window). And just count them.

I have tried user function for that under lapply(), but it's slow too.

In other words it shall be a rollmean() for ordered vectors that decides which element belongs to window not by its position, but by its value. Or dynamically changes window size based on vector values (same for other point of view).

Is there in R anything for that?
Or any other faster method to do that?

Comment: How big will your typical window length be?

Comment: If `window` contains your window length, then `rollapply(FF,width=window,FUN=table)/window` does what you want *for smaller instances* (I just used `MM=10`, `NN=100`, `window=3`). More generally, you will likely run into memory issues. Your output will be a matrix with `NN-window+1` rows and `MM` columns (`NN=5e6` and `MM=5e3` --> `2.5e10` entries, if `window` is small wrt `NN`). If you just store counts as (short) integers, this may work - if you store frequencies, you will likely run out of memory. It seems R may not be the right tool for this job.

Comment: window is 10^4~10^6. and up to 10^4 levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package might be of help for your problem:

```
library("devtools")
install_github("boRingTrees","mgahan")

# Bring in library
library("boRingTrees")
```

Here is an similar example to what you described. Note that you can change the number of cores if you need more speed. It should already be pretty fast because it utilizes the speed of the `data.table` package.

```
set.seed(1)
Trans_Dates <- as.Date(c(31,33,65,96,150,187,210,212,240,273,293,320,
                         32,34,66,97,151,188,211,213,241,274,294,321,
                         33,35,67,98,152,189,212,214,242,275,295,322),origin="2010-01-01")
Cust_ID <- c(rep(1,12),rep(2,12),rep(3,12))
Target <- rpois(36,3)
require("data.table")
data <- data.table(Trans_Dates,Cust_ID,Target)

data[,Roll:=rollingByCalcs(data=data,bylist="Cust_ID",dates="Trans_Dates",
        target="Target",lower=0,upper=31,incbounds=T,stat=mean,na.rm=T,cores=1)]
```

Comment: As I understand i would need to generate an unnecessary list of dates which is bad as dataset has few millions rows and they are in historical order already.
I ended up with writing a small tool in Qt C++ for that task.

Comment: It doesn't need dates, but good for you for getting this. You should probably post your solution as this is a community and people spent time trying to help you.